# File upload fails if I use camera to upload a picture

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I am trying to upload a picture from the existing files it is working without any issues. But when I choose a file directly by clicking from the **camera from mobile** it fails showing "CORS Error". I added "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and I removed it none of them helps.

```
userData.getRequestCallbackWithPrescription = (req, result) => {
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("call_request[call_time]", req.call_time);
        req.image_upload.forEach((obj, i) => {
            data.append(`prescription_upload[image_upload][${i}][image]`, obj.file, obj.file.name)
        })
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: globalUrl + '/api/' + apiVersion + '/customer/web/call_requests',
            headers: {   
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                'Content-Type': undefined,
                "X-Auth-Token": $rootScope.UserDetails.Auth,
            },
            data
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                return result(response.data);
            }, function (response) {
                return result(response);
            });
    }
```

Please help me with finding the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just compressed the image and uploaded it. It works!